# Cascade on delete not cascading with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I have a simple sqlite database with two tables. When I manually delete (using SQLite Expert)an entry in table DataSets, the coresponding entry in OneD is deleted as expected. When I delete an entry in DataSets from Entity Framework it does not cause the coresponsing entry in One D to be deleted. There is no error generated.

Any idea why?

Regards

Here is the database definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [DataSets] (
  [DataSetId] INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT FAIL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [Description] TEXT(128));

CREATE TABLE [OneD] (
  [OneDId] INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT FAIL PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT ABORT AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [DataSetId] INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT FAIL UNIQUE ON CONFLICT ABORT REFERENCES [DataSets]([DataSetId]) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  [StockSheetLength] INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT FAIL);
```

Here is how I delete the entry from EF

```
        var dataSets = from ds in context.DataSets select ds;
        foreach (var ds in dataSets)
            context.DataSets.DeleteObject(ds);

        context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the SQLite documentation: http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards
>   compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database
>   connection separately.

Could this be your problem? I don't know if your Entity Framework turns it on by default with:

```
  sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

**Edit:** Looking a bit further i stumbled across this: http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010_06_01_archive.html

> The Entity Framework is actually an ADO.NET data provider that is
>   itself wrapping an ADO.NET data provider (SQLite, to be specific).
>   Normally, the Entity Framework will open a database connection
>   whenever it needs one; these automatically-opened connections are
>   automatically closed when the Entity Framework is finished with it.
>   This default behavior works well with SQL Server due to its ADO.NET
>   provider's connection pooling. However, it does not work well with
>   SQLite, due to various "properties" existing on the SQLite connection
>   itself. One example is "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", which enforces
>   foreign keys only for that SQLite database connection. If the Entity
>   Framework opens and closes its connections at will, then SQLite
>   PRAGMAs such as these are lost.

Answer (score 9):

The problem can be solved by enabling foreign keys in the connection string:

```
data source=mydb.db;foreign keys=true
```

Comment: When I add foreign keys=true to the connection string, I get this error: {"The underlying provider failed on Open."}

Answer (score 7):

here's my solution to that problem:

```
db.Connection.StateChange += ConnectionStateChange;

void ConnectionStateChange(object sender, System.Data.StateChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentState == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
         db.ExecuteStoreCommand("PRAGMA foreign_keys = true;");            
}
```